# toggle div height

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I am building a site in Drupal. I want to toggle the height of a div element between 100% and 200px. I have tried the toggle function but it is not supporting two callback functions(confused in this case).

I tried flags that will check the height of div tag and it will set the height as per the current height. Since, I have three div tags with same class and I want this toggle functionality in all three, so this idea also fails in this case.

Also, when the height is changed to 100% it happens without easing effect, when the height is changed to 200px the easing effect works.

Comment: Can you post your code / toggle function?

Comment: i simplified the above two codes for easy understanding. heres the actual code:http://jsfiddle.net/KLEbe/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/Z4Z8D/5/

Comment: try changing `.css()` to use `.animate()`

Comment: @rkw could you please make yourself more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML :

```
<div class="target"> Hi </div>
<div class="target"> Hi 2</div>
<div class="target"> Hi 3</div>
<a href="#" id="button">Button</a>
```

CSS :

```
.target {
    width: 100px;

}
.someClass {
    background: #f00;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("div.target").toggleClass("someClass",100);
    return false;
});
```

If that's not good enough for you, check this one, with easing effects:
http://jsfiddle.net/6FwUf/4/

EDIT: 
I've modified your code, try doing this :

```
$("a.artist-page-read-more").toggle(
     function() {
         $(this).parents("div.panel-pane").siblings("div.panel-pane.pane-entity-field").find("div.field-items").animate({height: "100%"}, "slow");
     },
    function(){
         $(this).parents("div.panel-pane").siblings("div.panel-pane.pane-entity-field").find("div.field-items").animate({height: "200px"}, "slow");
       }   
   );
```

Comment: Could you please setup a working example of your code on jsfiddle ? Because I don't understand why 2 functions are not working for you.